# how to move object(shapes ) with the help of keyboard in javafx?

Tags: javafx, event-handling

I am trying to build a JavaFX application in which I am unable to move the rectangle with the help of the keyboard with the help of controls buttons it works fine but with the keyevent handler it seems that it is not even calling the function.
here is my controller class code
please do give some suggestions
sorry for the inconvenient language i actually dont know how to ask questions
thankyou

```
package sample;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.*;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    public Circle circle;
    public Button b1;
    public Button b2;
    public Rectangle rectangle;
    public Pane pane;
    double dx = 4;
    double dy = 4;
    int count = 0;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {


        KeyFrame k = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100),
            e - > {

                circle.setLayoutX(circle.getLayoutX() + dx);
                circle.setLayoutY(circle.getLayoutY() + dy);
                if (circle.getLayoutX() < 30 | circle.getLayoutX() >= 600) {
                    dx = -dx;
                }
                if (circle.getLayoutY() < 30 | circle.getLayoutY() >= 400) {
                    dy = -dy;
                }
                //condition for collision with rectangle
                Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(circle, rectangle);
                if (intersect.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() != -1) {
                    dy = -dy;
                }
            }
        );

        Timeline t = new Timeline(k);
        t.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        t.play();


    }


    public void move(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
            case A:
                rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + 10);
                break;
            case B:
                rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + 10);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please do some research before posting (you are not the first developer with your requirement, you'll find examples here :) - when stuck with adjusting a working example to your specific requirements, provide a [mcve] demonstrating unexpected behavior)

Comment: `import java.awt.*;` may cause issues. I would remove it if it's not 100% necessary.

Comment: See if you can get some ideas from https://github.com/sedj601/PongFX/blob/master/src/pongfx/FXMLDocumentController.java

Answer (score -1):

Try..

```
public void move(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
        case A:
            Platform.runLater(()->rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + 10));
            break;
        case B:
            Platform.runLater(()->rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + 10));
            break;
    }
}
```